# Why is this attibute on a subject not being set in a rails rspec model spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, model, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a spec testing a model that looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe SomeModel, type: :model do

  subject { described_class.new(test_amount: 99) }

  describe 'validates a column' do
    it 'does some validations' do
      expect(subject).to validate_presence_of(:test_amount)
    end
  end
end
```

And a model that looks like this:

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  validates :test_amount, presence: true
end
```

And in the schema it's column looks like this with a not-null set:

```
t.integer "test_amount", default: 0, null: false
```

No matter what I do or where I put the code, test_amount is always nil when being tests and errors.
I've tried moving the test lines around, putting the subject in a before etc, but always the
database is throwing a non-null error and even if I raise in the model code
the test_amount value is not 99 it is nil. If I raise the test value in
a before like this:

```
before do
  raise subject.test_amount
end
```

That does result in a 99, however if I remove this, it is always nil and throws an error when it gets to the expect part of the test.

What am I missing in order to get this test to work, I just cannot seem to get the `test_amount` to set to 99 when being tested in the actual test step.

The test always throws the error:

`PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "test_amount" of relation "some_models" violates not-null constraint` or similar, I have but in before-validations to check the value of `test_amount` and it does not get set.

Thanks for you help, I feel like there's something really basic I'm missing here.

Comment: The `validate_presence_of` matcher will not attempt to save the record to the database, so you should not be seeing a PG error. That test works just fine when I ran it in isolation. Most likely you have some other test code in the same spec that's saving the record and causing the error.

Comment: it would be easy to answer if you post the whole spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, verify that -

1. The record is persisted.
2. Once persisted, then check the attribute value.

Moreover, try moving this line inside the `describe` block -

```
 subject { described_class.new(test_amount: 99) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance this is due to not running migrations in the test environment?

```
bundle exec rake db:prepare RAILS_ENV=test

# or for rack applications

bundle exec rake db:prepare RACK_ENV=test
```

Other than this I would think that because we aren't **saving** the record to the database. We wouldn't expect validations to be ran.

As per [this documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#validations) we are only expecting to run validations when `Record#save` or `Record#save!` has been called.

When running `Record#new` we are creating a new instance but **not saving** to our database.

> Using the new method, an object can be instantiated without being saved:

When running [`Record#create`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create) we initialize the record and then save this to the database by calling `Record#save`.

Answer (score -1):

You can write test cases for the `presence` validation with [valid?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Validations/valid%3F) and [errors](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) methods like below:

```
RSpec.describe SomeModel, type: :model do

  subject { described_class.new(test_amount: test_amount) }

  describe 'validates a column' do
    context 'when valid test_amount'
      let(:test_amount) { 99 }
      it 'does not throw error' do
        expect(subject.valid?).to eq(true)
        expect(subject.errors[:test_amount].size).to eq(0)
      end
    end

    context 'when invalid test_amount'
      let(:test_amount) { nil }
      it 'throws error' do
        expect(subject.valid?).to eq(false)
        expect(subject.errors[:test_amount].size).to eq(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```